# extglob behaves different in bash of Fedora and Debian

Tags: bash, wildcards

Fedora 31 and Debian 10 behaves different when I run the following command:

```
/bin/ls /bin/!(znew) | /bin/grep znew
```

Fedora it outputs nothing, but Debian it does:

```
znew
```

`znew` exists on Fedora, if I run `/bin/ls /bin/znew | /bin/grep znew` I get:

```
/bin/znew
```

(On Debian it happens the same thing)

I've checked bash configuration on both distros, the only difference I've found is that on Fedora I have:

```
cdable_vars     on
cdspell         on
dirspell        on
login_shell     on
```

On Debian those options are disabled, and **`extglob` is on on both distros**

Note: Command `grep` it's only used here to make the listing shorter

Versions:

- On Fedora: 5.0.11
- On Debian: 5.0-4

Why does it exist such a difference?

**UPDATE 1**

/bin is a symlink to /usr/bin on both Debian and Fedora.

This is the output of searching for znew string in filenames:

```
updatedb && locate  znew
/usr/bin/znew
/usr/share/man/man1/znew.1.gz
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08/5a35247ad1c941455f2f9c4139d9136c6c0662e1b04e5b3c56121e7f67ba0100/files/bin/znew
/var/lib/lxc/centos/rootfs/usr/bin/znew
/var/lib/lxc/centos/rootfs/usr/share/man/man1/znew.1.gz
/var/lib/lxc/opensuse/rootfs/usr/bin/xznew
/var/lib/lxc/opensuse/rootfs/usr/bin/znew
/var/lib/lxc/opensuse/rootfs/usr/share/man/man1/xznew.1.gz
/var/lib/lxc/opensuse/rootfs/usr/share/man/man1/znew.1.gz
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've find something interesting, there was in Debian a symlink of /bin/X11 pointing to `.` after removing it behaves as in Fedora.

Comment: On Debian, do you have a subdirectory in `/bin` with `znew` in it?

Comment: No, I haven't. Perhaps, it's worth to mention that /bin is on both Debian and Fedora a symlink.

Comment: What does `find -L /bin/ -print0 | LC_ALL=C sed -zn /znew/l | tr '\0' '\n'` give you?

Comment: I'd bet you have a `/bin/bin -> /usr/bin` symlink (a symlink called `bin` that points to `/usr/bin` (or to `/bin` or to `.`) in `/bin`).

Comment: [Indeed, there is a `/usr/bin/X11` symlink to `.` in the `x11-common` package](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2FX11&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any). I lost my bet, but I was close :-)

Comment: You was really very close, I don't undertand why does a symlink of `/usr/bin/X11` to `.` exist.

Comment: Years ago, X11 utility tended to be in different utilities, in `/usr/bin/X11` or in something like `/usr/X11R6/bin` and `/usr/bin/X11` would be a symlink to it. At some point Debian like many others moved them to /usr/bin alongside the other non-X11 utilities, so it adapted the /usr/bin/X11 symlink to point to that new location (so for instance, `/usr/bin/X11/xterm` remains a valid path to `xterm`).

Answer (score 2):

Given that the `extglob` shell option is set in your interactive `bash` session, the command

```
ls /bin/!(znew) | grep znew
```

would first run `ls` with all the names in `/bin` that is not `znew` as arguments.  If this list of names includes names of subdirectories, `ls` would output the contents of those subdirectories (since `-d` was not used with `ls`).  If one of these subdirectories contain the name `znew`, then the `grep` would match and output that name.

The contents of the unknown subdirectory of `/bin` would be listed by `ls` without prepending the names in it with any directory path. Hence, if a subdirectory contains the `znew` name, it would be outputted as `znew` rather than as `/bin/some-dir/znew`.

When `ls` is used as in

```
ls /bin/znew | grep znew
```

it would output the string `/bin/znew` rather than `znew` (if that pathname exists).  It does this because it is outputting the specific pathname of a file given as a command line argument, not the contents of a directory given as an argument.

A situation like this could possibly have occurred if someone tried to create a symbolic link for `/usr/bin` called `/bin` while `/bin` was already a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`, or while `/bin` was still a directory.

In an update to the question, it is revealed that `/bin/X11` was a symbolic link to `.` (the current directory).  This means that `znew` would have been accessible through the pathname `/bin/X11/znew`.

**So, in conclusion**, what is happening is that the `/bin/!(znew)` globbing pattern expanded to a list of pathnames, one of these being `/bin/X11` (but not `/bin/znew`).  The `ls` utility would then get all pathnames, including `/bin/X11` as arguments. When `ls` gets to list `/bin/X11`, the contents of the `/bin` directory is listed, due to `/bin/X11` pointing there.  The `grep` utility then picks out `znew`, which will part of the output of `ls`.

---

As Stéphane Chazelas [points out in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585295/extglob-behaves-different-in-bash-of-fedora-and-debian/585302?noredirect=1#comment1089981_585302), you would get the same effect if there is a file in `/bin` on your Debian system that has a name containing a newline followed by the string `znew` (possibly followed by another newline and maybe further characters).

Since the name is not exactly the string `znew`, it would match the pattern `/bin/!(znew)` and `ls` would output this single name as

```
/bin/something
znew
maybe more
```

and `grep` would extract `znew` from that output.

Comment: Another possible (though also unlikely) explanation could be that there's a `$'/bin/whatever\nznew'` file in `/bin`

Comment: An explanation that sounds likely is that  `/bin` contains a symlink to itself or `/usr/bin` like if someone did a `ln -s /usr/bin /bin` whilst `/bin` was already there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good one! I forgot some Linuxes have this symbolic link, and it sounds plausible that an admin might have intended to set this up on the Debian system, but failed (or didn't clean up a failed attempt).

Comment: In any case that can't by a problem with bash globs as if `!(znew)` failed not to match on `znew`, you would get `/bin/znew` as output, not just `znew`.